# What is the correct proposition?

Tags: logic, solution-verification

We have a question regarding the following problem:

**Prove that the inference is valid.**

All politicians are rich.

No student is rich.

No student is a politician.

Our question regarding this problem and how we tried to solve it:

We used:

P→R (all politicians are rich)

R→¬S (no student is rich)

P→¬S (no student is a politician)

By making a truth table for these propositions, we found out that it is a valid inference as all three premises are 1 and not 1 1 0 for example. (it is valid and satisfiable though)

HOWEVER: If we use the following proposition for the ''no student is rich''.. ¬(R→S) ..We will not get a valid inference from the truth table.

**What is the difference between: R→¬S and ¬(R→S). Or S→¬R? Which one could be interpreted as ''no student is rich''? And why?**

Thank you!

Comment: You need to use *quantifiers* and *predicates* in your answers!

Comment: See amWhy's suggestion : e.g "all politicians are rich" must be translated as $\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow R(x))$ that is : "for all $x$, if $x$ is a Politician, then $x$ is Rich".

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
Is it not possible to use propositions here and if so, why?

Comment: No, propositions do not work. Did you read the comments or answer? You (and others that form, with you, a "we") need to hit the books. You need to understand how to translate to predicate logic *before* you can hope to write proofs using it!

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, you need to use *quantifiers and predicates* in your solutions.

$\forall x$ to express "all x", $\exists x$ to express  "there exists an x" or "some x..."

We can consider our universe of discourse to be all people. We can set up our translation key, to use express and symbolize the predicates we need.

$P(x):$ "x is a politician", $\;R(x):\;$ "x is rich", $\;S(x):\;$ "x is a student"

For the first statement we can start by writing the statement as follows: "For all x, if $x$ is a politician then $x$ is rich." Using our translation key: then, that's expressed $$\forall x(P(x)\rightarrow R(x))$$

---

Now try translating the next two statements. Hint: for both, one way to symbolize "there is no x" is by negating the existentially quantified $x$: $$\lnot \exists x$$ essentially conveys "it is not the case that there exists an $x$ such that...", or less formally, "There is no x (such that) ..."

Example: To translate "No reptile is a mammal,"  we can take our universe of discourse to be all animals, use $R(x)$ to denote "x is a reptile", and $M(x)$ to denote "x is a mammal". The logical translation would be: $$\lnot \exists x (R(x) \land M(x))$$

Answer (score 0):

To use propositional logic on this problem, you would have to pick a single person to use as a typical example:

P: John is a politician:

R: John is rich:

S: John is a student

so
(1) P→R: would mean; If John is a politician then he is rich.

(2) S→¬R: If John is a student, then he is not rich

(3) S→¬P: If John is a student, then he is not a politician.

(4) R→¬S: if John is rich, then he is not a student. This is the contrapositive of (2) and is logically equivalent to it. You could use (1) and (4) to conclude:

(5) P→¬S: If John is a politician, then he is not a student, and then its contrapositive

(6) S→¬P: If John is a student he is not a politician.

(7) ¬(R→S) is equivalent to the claim R & ¬S: John is rich and John is not a student. This is more than you can claim, based on the assumptions given.

The assumption that John is any arbitrary member of your domain of discourse might well be the middle part of a more complete and formal proof of your desired inference. 
However, the words "all, some, and none" normally indicate you should be using 
quantifiers and predicates, and you are missing some important steps at the beginning and end by using propositional logic.